# Element extraction from multiple arrays in Numpy/Scipy

Tags: arrays, numpy, scipy

I have three numpy arrays: A, B, and C. I have to extract '1' that is common (pixel wise) to any two of the given arrays, and set all other elements as 0.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])              

B = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1]])

C = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1]])
```

The expected answer would be:

```
result = np.array([[1,0,0,0,1],
               [1,0,0,0,1],
               [1,0,0,0,1]])
```

How can I do it using Numpy/Scipy? A faster performance is necessary since in my real problem, the number of arrays are 50s and the size of each array is (3000, 3000), and I have to extract the '1' if common to 30 arrays.

Comment: result = (A & B) | (A & C) | (B & C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum them and then use boolean operations to check whether the elements are `>=2`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])              

B = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1],
               [1,1,1,1,1]])

C = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1],
               [0,0,0,0,1]])

D = A + B + C

D = (D >= 2).astype(int)

print(D)
#[[1 0 0 0 1]
# [1 0 0 0 1]
# [1 0 0 0 1]]
```

`(D >= 2).astype(int)` will return True for each value that is `>=2` and False otherwise. You then convert it from True/False values to 1/0 values using `.astype(int)`.

You mention in your question that in your real case you could have up to 50 arrays? Either store them in a list and use `sum()` or store them in a 3-dimensional numpy array and use `your_numpy_array.sum()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it really work for my 50 arrays when extracting common in any 30 arrays as follows: (D >= 30).astype(int)?

Comment: The shape of my array in the real case is (50L, 3000L, 3000L). How can I apply axis?